# Comparing pointer values in if statement

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement, compare

4Why this block throws memory error:

```
uint8_t buffer[ 8 ] = { 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

if ( *((uint32_t *)(&buffer[ 0 ])) == *((uint32_t *)(&buffer[ 4 ])) + 1 )
    return TRUE;
```

While this block works:

```
uint8_t buffer[ 8 ] = { 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
uint32_t comp1 = *((uint32_t *)(&buffer[ 0 ]));
uint32_t comp2 = *((uint32_t *)(&buffer[ 4 ]));

if ( comp1 == comp2  + 1 )
    return TRUE;
```

Comment: It works perfectly as I expected, what do you mean with **memory error**?

Comment: In microcontroller, it throws HardFaultException.

Comment: Are you aware that teh values in `buffer` are octal? It doesn't matter to the problem but just to be sure.

Comment: Yes, these are hexadecimal characters.

Comment: They are not, they are octal, it's not the same, `0x03` is hex.

Comment: Ok, I fixed. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: the problem is somewhere else, if you want to get help post the rest of the code, the problem is not reproducible with the code above, something elese might by causing the problem to the code above.

Comment: Could it be an alignment problem? Maybe your hardware requires `int`s to sit at 4-byte borders, which `comp2` currently does not. (Your test at the end should therefore not be true.)

Comment: Program counter does not increment after if statement. HardFaultException is called.

Comment: @blabla Did you mean `&buffer[4]` ? Here it looks like you want to compare 3 and 2+1, but `&buffer[3]` points on 0x00.

Comment: It does sound like an alignment problem indeed. Which MCU is this?

Comment: Yes, I meant that. I fixed the error. Thanks.

Comment: Try to replace `(uint32_t*)` by `(__packed uint32_t *)`. It should fix the problem if alignment is the cause.

Comment: @blabla The simplified code does not reproduce the error.

Comment: @Lundin, I also call the simplified method in MCU and I got the same error. Maybe it's specific for MCU?

Comment: @ElderBug it worked as you advised. What is that for? If you anser the question, I'll accept your answer. Otherwise your advise would be in comments.

Comment: Again, which MCU are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may come from the alignment of the buffer. Since your buffer is declared as `uint8_t[]`, the compiler won't necessarily align it.

This usually isn't a problem (but often induce a small performance penalty), but some architecture refuse to access unaligned pointers. On these architecture, the unaligned access must be done in software.

Here I assume your HardFaultException comes from an ARM, and [this link](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka15414.html) suggests to use the `__packed` attribute to let the compiler know that the pointer might be unaligned. The compiler will then use a software unaligned access.

It should be noted that modern ARM don't have this problem anymore. The link talk about "Older ARM processors", and I didn't notice this problem on modern ARM.